# Request over https using R shiny and a python server

Tags: python, r, ssl, shiny, https

I have a python server that runs using an ssl wrapped socket. I am trying to send an https GET and POST request from an R-shiny client to the python server, yet I get the following error:

> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6565
> Warning: Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory: schannel: Failed to get certificate location for >c/cygwin64/home/user/Documents/server/cert.pem

My overarching goal is to type a text into the shiny R text input, send this text to the python server in the form of a POST request over a secure channel. The python server I will run the `interpreter()` function on the string I just sent and return to the R-shiny client the appropriate response.

This setup has worked when not using ssl-certificates, however, after implementing the python ssl wrapped socket, I have been getting this error.

I hope some of you might be able to illuminate me on this matter.

This is my python server

```
import ssl
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from io import BytesIO


def interpreter(val):
    if val == "Search":
        return "Searched"
    elif val == "Add":
        return "Added"
    else:
        return "Invalid statement"


class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/csv")
        self.end_headers()

        self.wfile.write(bytes(
            "<html><body><h1>HELLO world!</h1></body></html>", "utf-8"))

    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        body = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        print(body.decode())
        modified_body = interpreter(body.decode())
        print(modified_body)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        response = BytesIO()
        response.write(b'Received: ')
        response.write(body)
        response.write(b' End of request')
        self.wfile.write(response.getvalue())


httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8000), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, keyfile="key.pem",
                               certfile="cert.pem", server_side=True)
print("Server Running Now...")
httpd.serve_forever()
httpd.server_close()
print("Server Stopped")
```

And my shiny-R application is as follows

```
library(shiny)
library(httr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Request Module"),
  
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           textInput(inputId = "request", label="Enter Request Term"),
           actionButton(inputId = "getRequest", label="Get"),
           actionButton(inputId = "postRequest", label="Post")
           )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    wellPanel(
      htmlOutput(outputId = "resultOutput")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  url <- "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
  s_url <- "https://127.0.0.1:8000"
  httr::set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))
  
  certfile="c/cygwin64/home/user/Documents/server/cert.pem"
  keyfile="c/cygwin64/home/user/Documents/server/key.pem"
  
  observeEvent(input$getRequest,{
    getResponse <- GET(url = s_url,
                       config(sslcert=certfile, sslkey=keyfile))
    output$resultOutput <- renderPrint({
      getResponse$content
      }) 
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$postRequest,{
    
    reqMessage <- input$request
    postResult <- POST(url = s_url,
                       body = reqMessage,
                       content_type("text/csv"),
                       encoding = "UTF-8",
                       config(sslcert=certfile, sslkey=keyfile))
    
    processedResponse <- content(postResult, as="text", encoding = "UTF-8")
    output$resultOutput <- renderPrint({
      processedResponse
    }) 
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Are you missing the `:` in `C:/`? I've never used R before but I just thought I'd point it out.

Comment: There are a lot of problems that arise from using snake-oil or non-CA-signed certs, searching for `"curl" "Failed to get certificate location"` shows many approaches to resolve it.

Comment: It's not a problem to use `c/cygwin` instead of `C:/` this is an alternative way of typing paths when using cygwin. I know because I can access the file in R using the same path.